# Opening Multiple files from a directory C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to open files from a directory but everytime I display my files i have these 3 dots at the top. So for example the directory i open is called "My Documents" the output would be the 3 dots as follows 
.
..
Names.txt
Jobs.txt

Names.txt and Jobs.txt is the only output i want to achieve, could anyone help out.

My code

```
int getDoc(string doc, vector<string> &documents){

    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *dirp;
    if ((dp = opendir(doc.c_str())) == NULL){
        cout << "Error(" << errno << ") opening" << doc << endl;
        return errno;
    }
    while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL){
        documents.push_back(string(dirp->d_name));
    }
    closedir(dp);
    return 0;
}
```

by the way i use dirent.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3 dots are actually 2 directories. The first one named '.' refers to the current directory. If you will try to open it, it will lead you back to the same directory. For example, directory `C:\Users\Daniel` is equal to `C:\Users\Daniel\.`
The second directory is '..'. It refers to the parent directory. So `C:\Users` directory is equivalent to `C:\Users\Daniel\..`

Those 2 directories are not real. They are simulated by the operating system. If you don't want to print them, just start printing the list after skipping the first 2 elements. Those 2 directories are always listed first.

Answer (score 2):

`.` is current directory, `..` is upper level directory. if you don't want them, just filter them out.

Answer (score 0):

The directory `.` is the current directory. The directory `..` is the parent directory. So they will be on the list

Just like running the command `ls -a`